# How to connect my guitar pedal to a Pioneer DJ mixer?

Tags: electric-guitar, effects-pedal, dj, cable

Is it OK to connect directly my Line 6 PODxt Live pedal to a Pioneer DJ mixer MIC input?

It is not sounding. I did it like this:

I tried doing it by plugging the quarter inch jack into the Pioneer DJ mixer, and that plug comes from my pedal set Line 6 PODxt Live, and it's not sounding yet, even if I turn up the "Level" output knob of my pedal pretty high (I was afraid of doing that and break something of the mixer side  because that "Level" knob is pretty powerful. I have a 60W amp and I usually use that knob in about 20% of power and that's enough) but even turning that knob of my pedal more than 50% it still didn't sound. What is happening? Should I use my 60W amp as the "pre-amp" so the Pioneer DJ mixer hears me playing?

I'm writing this based also on this other question's top answer: [Is there a way to connect a guitar to a dj console?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/48687/is-there-a-way-to-connect-a-guitar-to-a-dj-console)

If the solution would be using an RCA-jack cable converter, should that work?

Edit: picture attached showing inputs of the mixer from the back and the model is DDJ T1.
[image]

Comment: Knowing the exact model might help. Generally plugging a line level device into a mic channel is not a good move; you could blow the ip amp.

Comment: Ok, so, better to convert my pedal line to an RCA black and white interface? I can tell you that the mixer has in fact that RCA input, but cannot yet tell you the version of that mixer. Thanks!

Comment: Let's not guess until we know what we're connecting to. At worst a clear picture of the jack field on the back.

Comment: Ok will do. We are a band. She is the DJ and I jazz her music with my Fly-V Dean installed Seymour Duncan humbuckers Alnico II Pro. Last time we had to connect my guitar to the speaker of the customer's, but next week, will have to be directly to her mixer. Have asked for the picture in fact. Will post. Thanks again!

Comment: Hi @Tetsujin here is the mixer model and a picture of the back inputs: it is a Pioneer DDJ T1 with RCA "AUX IN" input in the back, and an "MIC" input at the front. That MIC input at the front is the one not hearing my POD xt live pedal but , What if I get connected to that RCA input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple rule of thumb is that it is OK to plug microphones to microphone inputs. Things that are not microphones should not go to microphone inputs, unless you use a DI box that is an adapter specially for this purpose.

The Pod XT is not a microphone, so it should not go to microphone input. The manual says its outputs are line-level and can be switched between balanced and non-balanced mode. The best match on your mixer is the Aux input, which is line-level non-balanced. You need 1/4 inch plug to RCA cables for the connection, and the Pod XT should be set up for non-balanced output.

Comment: Thanks will do, it's part of another architecture I am about to do using this other question's conclusion (the A/B switch) https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/127676/how-to-listen-to-my-guitar-on-earphones-on-a-live-playing-gig-while-it-also-soun/127702#127702