# How to listen to my guitar on earphones on a live playing gig while it also sounds in the main monitor speakers, and switch off the guitar sometimes?

Tags: guitar, electric-guitar, effects-pedal, mixer, dj

I am playing with a DJ and the music is getting each time better. I'm jazzing her music with my Line 6 PODxt Live pedal and my Dean Fly-V with Seymour humbuckers doing awesome sustain and quality. The thing is that in some places the music is a little away from us to get 100% details of my audio and before some songs I need to adjust my effect before starting to play with the music she is playing.

How can I connect my earphones to my guitar in order I can switch the output to her Pioneer DJ mixer whenever I want? So I can adjust on the go, before making it sound on the main sound monitors, I mean.

Comment: I see XT Live has a headphone output. Do I guess it mutes the main outputs? Maybe there is a setting to prevent it from doing so?

Comment: Yes it has a headphone output but no it doesn't mute the other one. I wish that setting can be easily set when playing so I would activate it simply bye selecting another effect on the pedals. Do you know which setting can do that?

Comment: you could make a simple stomp box with two 1/4 female plugs and a latching switch to break the connection. You'd plug the out-to-dj to the box and then the box to the DJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about an A/B Box?  They are available in instrument and xlr versions. Output "A" is the DJ Mixer, output "B" is your headphone amp, and you just hit a button to switch outputs.

Comment: Thanks Edward with John's answer I arrived to that other option and it looks really interesting also because of the price :-)

Answer (score 6):

I believe this can easily be accomplished with an inexpensive compact mixing board. Run your Line 6 Pod into a stereo channel and the main output of the mixing board to the main sound input. The headphone jacks on these mixers almost always have a separate volume control. When you want to silently monitor lower the main output but leave the headphone volume up. When you are ready to send your signal to the mains just raise the volume of the main output.

Comment: That sounds great. Do you have mixing board samples? Of course looking for a cheap one but respecting the quality achieved by my hardware combination.

Comment: @Gudilbert we are not supposed to recommend gear on this site but companies like Mackie, Behringer, Yamaha and many others make compact mixers with about 2-4 channels and 3-6 inputs for $100US or less. @Tim’s idea of using an external volume pedal could also work well if your Pod has a headphone out that you can use for monitoring.

Answer (score 6):

John's solution was my first thought. But you may have your hands full of guitar at those moments. So augmenting the equipment needed with a couple of simple volume pedals placed in the signal train would alleviate that problem.

Comment: So a couple of simple volume pedals would do the trick awesome. Which ones can achieve it but also respecting the quality achieved by my hardware combination? Also looking for something cheap in this side :-)